# Get beginning of calendar week from current date() in

Tags: php, date, week-number

I find functions which return the week number for a given date. 
But instead, I would like to get the date of the first day of the particular calendar week returned. 
This would either be date() itself, or anything between date()-1 and date()-7.

Purpose: my site shall return events of this week. Right now, I only show the the range date()+7, which is not correct.

Thanks & Regards,
  Marcus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `strtotime()` function like this:

```
strtotime("next monday");
strtotime("this sunday");
strtotime("last sunday");
```

In your case:

```
strtotime("this monday");
```

As a result you have timestamp.

The second way is like this:

```
$day = date('w');
$week_start = date('m-d-Y', strtotime('-'.$day.' days'));
$week_end = date('m-d-Y', strtotime('+'.(6-$day).' days'));
```